# about strings in c++

Tags: c++, string, coding-style

This is the code for removing consecutive  words:

```
std::string unstretch(std::string word)
{
    std::string s;
    int k=0;

    for(int i=0;i<word.length();k++,i++)
    {
        if(word[i]!=word[i+1])
        {
            s[k]=word[i];
        }
        else
            k--;
    }
    s[k]='\0';
    return s;
}
```

This code works if we replace `string s` with `char s[50]`. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: `s[k]=word[i];` ==> `s.push_back(word[i]);` - You never give any initial size to `s`, therefore, `s[k] = ...` invokes *undefined behavior*. There is no "there" there. Fixing that, `s[k]='\0';` is pointless; get rid of it, along with `k`.

Answer (score 3):

`s` is an empty string. You cannot use `operator[]` on an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: Please give the poor OP a solution!

Comment: And... use s.reserve(word.length()); in place of c[50];

Comment: @jjw `reserve` does not allow you to access the "reserved" memory, so of course, no.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are treating string as a char array. Its not just a char array. So,

1. You don't need to keep an index to append
2. You don't need the null terminator

I think what your program does is remove the duplicate characters. This is how you would probably do it:

```
std::string unstretch(std::string word)
{
    std::string s;

    for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
    {
        if(word[i]!=word[i+1])
        {
            s += word[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: but if we want to access any elements of above string s,we will use index.But why we cannot use index here while assigning.

Comment: Because the string is empty. When you declared the char array, you specified the size to be 50. Hence, you can access kth element. By default, the string is empty. So there is nothing you can access. When I did +=, it means append this to whatever the string already has.